# Обмен данными в Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: phonegap, cordova, html, javascript

Решил попробовать для себя разработку мобильных приложений, используя фрэймворк Cordova. Да, знаю - способ не оптимальный. Наитивый код в разы лучше. Для изучения фрэймворка решил сделать простой клиент к новостному сайту. Благо дело у сайта есть RSS фид. Первая мысль была использовать Ajax запрос. Но кроссдоменные запросы браузером блокируются, а вариант использования JSONP подходит далеко не в каждом случае.

Итак, как же лучше поступить? Вводить промежуточный серер, получающий на входе XML и отдающий JSONP? Затратно по ресурсам.
Может быть,  есть другой выход? Как вообще организовывается обмен внешними даннымии в Cordova?